# PHP Solr 4.10 : SolrServerError "for input string : 10,00" on addDocument with setBoost(10)

Tags: php, solr, solr4

Didn't find an answer to my problem.

I'm using pecl SolR PHP with a SolR server 4.10.1. A SolrServerError occurs when i try to add a document with a boost set. The message is : "For input string: "10,0"" code : 500.

I did the following code :

```
//$boostDocument = 10.00;
$doc->setBoost($boostDocument);

foreach($data as $cle=>$valeur) {
    if(is_array($valeur) == TRUE) {
        foreach ($valeur as $val) {
            $doc->addField($cle, $val);
        }
    } else {
        $doc->addField($cle, $valeur);
    }
}

try {
    $this->solrClient->addDocument($doc, true); 
} catch (SolrServerException $e) {

}
```

Here is the result document I tried to add :

```
array(3) {
["document_boost"]=>
  float(10)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(3)
  ["fields"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(SolrDocumentField)#21 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(2) "id"
      ["boost"]=>
      float(0)
      ["values"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(6) "752891"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    object(SolrDocumentField)#22 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(4) "type"
      ["boost"]=>
      float(0)
      ["values"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "CAT"
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    object(SolrDocumentField)#23 (3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(11) "designation"
      ["boost"]=>
      float(0)
      ["values"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(23) "Good guy designation"
        [1]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Without the `$document->SetBoost(10.00)` no error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the locale setting in PHP, as certain locales use "," as the decimal separator (where US English uses "."), and this affects the casting from float to string when the Solr request is generated internally in the module.

You can force using the default conversion for C when PHP was compiled by using `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")` before making the request, or possibly (I haven't tried yet) by setting the boost as string directly instead (setBoost("10.00") or setBoost(10)).

You can use `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 0)` to get the current setting, so you can set it back after the request has been made.

Comment: Great ! I tried it and everything went fine. Thank you.